# EmguCV Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, exception, emgucv

I have the following code to display an image in imagebox using EmgucV:

```
    Capture capture;
    Image<Bgr, Byte> image;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Start);
    }
    void Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        capture = new Capture();
        image = capture.QueryFrame();
        imageBox1.Image = image;
    }
```

I get the exception `Attempted to read or write protected memory`. What do I need to do to correct this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an indication of possible native memory leak

I think there is an error in your code. Your `Start` method will get called many times (very often) during application lifetime.

It looks like you should use only one Capture object in your application.

Simply move your Capture instantiation to Form constructor:

```
Capture capture;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Capture);
    capture = new Capture();
}
void Capture(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imageBox1.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current fix for Emgu CV version 3.4.1 using Windows Form c#; add one button call it btnCapture, add one PictureBox control leave the name to its defaults for the purpose of this answer.  hope this code example helps

```
    public VideoCapture capture;
    private void btnCatpure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // each click a single frame will be capture and then display in the control.
        Mat iframe = new Mat();
        capture.Retrieve(iframe, 0);
        Mat grayFrame = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.CvtColor(iframe, grayFrame, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

        pictureBox1.Image =  iframe.Bitmap;
        pictureBox1.Image = grayFrame.Bitmap;
    }
```